# Restrict pan gesture from moving outside of the left and right sides of the screen’s frame

Tags: ios, swift3, uiimage, uipangesturerecognizer

I have an image view that pops up in the centre of the screen. You can pinch to zoom in or zoom out the image as well as move it horizontally. All these actions work perfectly. However I want to restrict the panning movements so users can't swipe beyond the left or right edges of the image. Below Ive posted screenshots along with explanations to show what I mean

Original View

[image: Original view]

Image moved to the right. At the moment you can see you can move it beyond the left edge of the image and it show black a black space. If the image width is equal to the screen width then I obviously want the pan gesture to be disable

[image]

Image zoomed in

[image]

Imaged moved to the left but again I want to be able to restrict the pan gesture to the edge of the image so there is no black space on the right of the image.

[image]

Ive tried looking around but I can't find anything that can help with my specific problem. Ive posted my code below. Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks in advance

```
func handlePan(_ gestureRecognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    guard let zoomView = gestureRecognizer.view else{return}

    if gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.began || gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.changed {
        let translation = gestureRecognizer.translation(in: self.view)
        if(gestureRecognizer.view!.center.x < 300) {
             gestureRecognizer.view!.center = CGPoint(x:gestureRecognizer.view!.center.x + translation.x, y: gestureRecognizer.view!.center.y)

        }else{

        gestureRecognizer.view!.center = CGPoint(x:299, y: gestureRecognizer.view!.center.y)

        }
        gestureRecognizer.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: zoomView) 
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you saying you want to restrict the he imageView from moving outside of the left and right of the screen’s frame?

Comment: is your imageView is in scrollview?

Comment: @LanceSamaria yes exactly. Do you know how I could achieve this? Sorry if my explanation wasn't clear enough

Comment: @KarthickRamesh no my imageView is not in a scrollview. I tried to add a scroll programmatically(because I'm not using storyboard) but I was having troubles

Comment: In the scrollView can you try bouncesZoom as false like scrollView.bouncesZoom = false

Answer (score 2):

I followed this [youtube video](https://youtu.be/3uyPdOOHCiM) to get it done.

I can't help you with the zoom but I can help you stop the imageView from moving outside of the left and right sides when NOT zooming.

You didn't give any context as to wether or not your `imageView` was created in Storyboard or programmatically. The one in my example is programmatic and it's named `orangeImageView`.

Create a new project then just copy and paste this code inside of the View Controller. When you run the project you will see an orange imageView that you can move around but it won't go beyond the left or right side of the screen. I didn't bother with the top or bottom because it wasn't part of your question.

**Follow Steps 1 - 8** inside `@objc func panGestureHandler(_ gestureRecognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer)`  for an explanation of what each step does and how it works.

Replace the `orangeImageView` with the `imageView` your using:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

// create frame in viewDidLoad
let orangeImageView: UIImageView = {
    let imageView = UIImageView()
    imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    imageView.backgroundColor = .orange
    return imageView
}()

var panGesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // create a frame for the orangeImageView and add it as a subview
    orangeImageView.frame = CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 100, height: 100)
    view.addSubview(orangeImageView)

    // initialize the pangesture and add it to the orangeImageView
    panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(panGestureHandler(_:)))
    orangeImageView.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)
}

@objc func panGestureHandler(_ gestureRecognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer){

    // 1. use these values to restrict the left and right sides so the orangeImageView won't go beyond these points
    let leftSideRestrction = self.view.frame.minX
    let rightSideRestriction = self.view.frame.maxX

    // 2. use these values to redraw the orangeImageView's correct size in either Step 6 or Step 8 below
    let imageViewHeight = self.orangeImageView.frame.size.height
    let imageViewWidth = self.orangeImageView.frame.size.width

    if gestureRecognizer.state == .changed || gestureRecognizer.state == .began {

        let translation: CGPoint = gestureRecognizer.translation(in: self.view)
        gestureRecognizer.view!.center = CGPoint(x: gestureRecognizer.view!.center.x  + translation.x, y: gestureRecognizer.view!.center.y + translation.y)
        gestureRecognizer.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: self.view)

        /*
         3.
         -get the the upper left hand corner of the imageView's X and Y origin to get the current location of the imageView as it's dragged across the screen.
         -you need the orangeImageView.frame.origin.x value to make sure it doesn't go beyond the left or right edges
         -you need the orangeImageView.frame.origin.y value to redraw it in Steps 6 and 8 at whatever Y position it's in when it hits either the left or right sides
        */
        let imageViewCurrentOrginXValue = self.orangeImageView.frame.origin.x
        let imageViewCurrentOrginYValue = self.orangeImageView.frame.origin.y

        // 4. get the right side of the orangeImageView. It's computed using the orangeImageView.frame.origin.x + orangeImageView.frame.size.width
        let imageViewRightEdgePosition = imageViewCurrentOrginXValue + imageViewWidth

        // 5. if the the orangeImageView.frame.origin.x touches the left edge of the screen or beyond it proceed to Step 6
        if imageViewCurrentOrginXValue <= leftSideRestrction {

            // 6. redraw the orangeImageView's frame with x: being the far left side of the screen and Y being where ever the current orangeImageView.frame.origin.y is currently positioned at
            orangeImageView.frame = CGRect(x: leftSideRestrction, y: imageViewCurrentOrginYValue, width: imageViewWidth, height: imageViewHeight)
        }

        // 7. if the the orangeImageView.frame.origin.x touches the right edge of the screen or beyond it proceed to Step 8
        if imageViewRightEdgePosition >= rightSideRestriction{

            // 8. redraw the orangeImageView's frame with x: being the rightSide of the screen - the orangeImageView's width and y: being where ever the current orangeImageView.frame.origin.y is currently positioned at
            orangeImageView.frame = CGRect(x: rightSideRestriction - imageViewWidth, y: imageViewCurrentOrginYValue, width: imageViewWidth, height: imageViewHeight)
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Hi Lance thank you very much for the detail response. It restricts the lateral panning when the image is not zoomed which is perfect and answers the first part of my question. But now I need to apply the same method somehow for when the image is zoomed in

Comment: Ok I've added more code under Edited in my question to give you a better idea of what Im doing. zoomView is actually my imageView which is orangeImageView that you used in your example. Please check my code again

Comment: I’m not familiar with pinch and zoom (i never used it) so it would take me a couple of days to figure this out. That’s part of the reason I said ask a new question. You might find someone who specializes in pinch and zoom. If I were you I’d create a new question and ask “How to prevent a zoomed in image with pan gesture attached from panning outside the screen’s frame?”

Comment: Ok no problem. I will send you the link once I post a new question

Comment: j.iese, you should mark lance samaria's answer as correct one if it served the purpose.